# search elements in an array in java

Tags: java

I'm wondering what kind method should I use to search the elements in an array and what data structure to store the return value

For example a txt file contains following

> 123 Name  line  Moon night table
>   124 Laugh Cry Dog
>   123 quote line make pet table
>   127 line array hello table

and the search elements are line+table 
I read every line as an string and then spilt by space

the output should like this

> 123 2 (ID 123 occurs twice that contains the search elements)
>   127 1

I want some suggestions of what kind method to search the elements in the array and what kind data structure to store the return value (the ID and the number of occurs. I'm thinking hashmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the text file and store each line that ends with table in `ArrayList<String>`. Then use contains for each element in `ArrayList<String>`. Store result in `HashMap<key,value>` where key is ID and value is Integer which represent number of times ID occurs.

Comment: Thanks. So I have to use loop to check the element if there are multiples search elements?

Comment: You need to search all elements of ArrayList  and increment value of  HashMap  accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would keep reading through the file line by line, there's really no other way of going about it other than that.

Second, to pick out the rows to save, you don't need to do the split (assumption: they all end in (space)table). You can just get them by using:

```
if (line.endsWith(" table"))
```

Then, I would suggest using a `Map<String, Integer>` datatype to store your information. This way, you have the number of the table (key) and how many times if was found in the file (value).

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
....reading file....
if (line.endsWith(" table")) {
    String number = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "))
    if (!map.containsKey(number)) {
        map.put(number, 1);
    } else {
        Integer value = map.get(number);
        value++;
        map.put(number, value);
    }
}
```